# How to calculate Return of investment using ethereum raw data

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have raw data of ethereum and i want to calculate the return of investment over-time by adding an extra column named as ROI but i am not sure what formula to use. 
I have 12 months of data and i want to calculate return of investment of each month.

Can you please help me with this.

Below is how my data looks like (it is only 1 month data)-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could start by defining when you invested, at what price you did that, and how many shares you bought.
Formula you looking for is a very simple math calculation.

Here is an example:

`=Adj Close / your_price * ShareQty / 100 - 100%`